# align div next to input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using Jorn Zaefferer's Autocomplete query plugin, http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/ and I wanted to add a button that will load all the elements the same as combobox.

So, I created a method that puts a div with image as background next to an input text:

```
var createDownArrow = function (input, request, options) {
    var defaults = {
        downArrowClass: 'autocomplete_DownArrow'
    };
    options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

    var offset = $(input).offset();
    var width = typeof options.width == 'string' || options.width > 0 ? options.width : $(input).width();
    var element = $('<div/>').addClass(options.downArrowClass).appendTo(document.body).
        css({ position: 'absolute', top: offset.top, left: offset.left + width}).click(function () {
            if (request && typeof request == 'function') {
                request();
            }
        });
};
```

the input text has the following css:

```
border: 1px solid #888888;
height:15px;
font-weight: normal;
font-size: 12px;
font-family: Arial (Hebrew);
padding:0px;
margin:0xp;
```

this is the div css:

```
   background-image:url(drop.jpg);
    background-position:top right;
    height:17px;
    width:17px;
    cursor:pointer;
```

and using this function on the input in the html:

```
<br /><br /><br /><br />
<input type="text" id="test" />
```

I get the result:
[image: pic1]

Which you can see is not the desire result.

How can I align the div next to the input?   (I am using direction:rtl)

Comment: It is true, that you using also jquery?

Comment: try enclosing input and the div in a container, float them

Comment: @Ibu: The desired result is that the div will be aligned next to the input text.

Comment: @reporter: You right, I am using also JQuery.

Comment: @Litek: I gave the div absolute position because I don't want it appect the dom. I am trying to align it properly with "top" and "left" css parameters.

Comment: in the div and the image first then input, then float the image right

Comment: @Ibu: I have an input tag and I want all the other elements I add to be positiond absolute.

Comment: with float you have the guaranty that the image will always be in the right spot.. no matter what browser, maybe you should re-evaluate your use of position

Comment: @Ibu, @Litek: This is an autocomplete plugin with the possibility to act like combobox. I can't wrap everything in a div because then each time I use it - it will break line. Moreover, I use this plugin in this way: $(input).autocomplete() and not $(div).autocomplete().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve this, I canceled the absolute position and added display:inline-block to the div. Then I just inserted in before the input and thats all.

Answer (score 0):

try enclosing in label tag

```
<label for="in"><img src=" " /><input name="in" /></label>
```

Comment: I have an input tag and I want all the other elements I add to be positiond absolute.

Answer (score 0):

Write up your example that statically includes the arrow at all times in the html.  When that works, replace the arrow's html by javascript that can generate it, and you'll be fine.

In more detail, I think you've got a problematic approach; you should use the right tool for the right job.  So while it's possible to do what you want by manual positioning, you really don't want to be getting into this quagmire: Javascript is a poor tool for this.  You probably can't get around using *some* javascript, but your life will be much easier if you do as much as possible in HTML+CSS - tools explicitly made for layout.  In particular, that means making your arrow button statically *first*, and *then* adding exactly the html that works to the DOM-tree, rather that trying to manually control layout by computing width+height+position of the input; which you're almost certainly going to get wrong (not to mention when things get tricky, e.g. with `overflow:scroll` and the like).

Oh, and you could get rid of the `<br/>` tags and simply make the input `display:block` with a `margin-top`.

One possible CSS approach would be to follow the button by width-0 span (inline element) containing a position absolute (don't affect layout) block that shows whatever you want. E.g.: http://jsfiddle.net/emn13/nvY2F/

To get this to work as a plugin, you'd write javascript to create the span and div in the html; preferably the css would be in a linked stylesheet, but you could use inline styles too, of course.  The CSS transitions are just for fun, of course.

Comment: I've added a jsfiddle that probably has at least roughtly the layout you want.

Comment: If that bothers you (and it doesn't bother actual browsers) then make that a span as well.  You could make it pretty much anything, as long as you can style it.  I've updated the jsfiddle to use a span.